# replacing text with preg_replace_callback and str_replace

Tags: php, regex

Okay, so I'm trying to replace really long quotes in my websites comments section that uses bbcode, what I'm trying to do is encase long quotes in a collapse I already have coded in js and css.

My problem is that it will do the first quote, then any other quotes vanish. I'm obviously missing something, but this is my first time using callbacks like this.

Here's my php code right now to do this:

```
$body = preg_replace_callback("/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is",
function($matches)
{
    if (strlen($matches[1]) >= '1000')
    {
        $matches[0] = str_replace($matches[0], '<div class="box"><div class="collapse_container"><div class="collapse_header"><span>Long quote, click to expand</span></div><div class="collapse_content">' . $matches[1] . '</div></div></div>', $matches[0]);
        return $matches[0];
    }
}, $body);
```

Some example text:

```
[quote]aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[/quote]

[quote]booohoo[/quote]

[quote]new quoting[/quote]

[b]test[/b]
```

Comment: Just move the `return $matches[0];` outside the `ìf`block.

Comment: @Liam Dawe I'm an author of the library designed to handle shortcodes and BBCodes of any kind. Please take a look, it'll definitely help your use case: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . If you need any help, just open an issue and I'll give you a hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the return `$matches[0]` code outside the `if` block:

```
function($matches)
{
    if (strlen($matches[1]) >= '1000') {
        $matches[0] = str_replace($matches[0], '<div class="box"><div class="collapse_container"><div class="collapse_header"><span>Long quote, click to expand</span></div><div class="collapse_content">' . $matches[1] . '</div></div></div>', $matches[0]);
    }
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Also, I advise to unroll your lazy matching regex as follows:

```
'~\[quote\]([^[]*(?:\[(?!/quote\])[^[]*)*)\[/quote\]~i'
```

See [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT3oV2/1) (30 steps) and [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT3oV2/2) (2025 steps).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/lXKxqM)

Answer (score 0):

Phps preg* functions are acting greedy by default. They will match the longest possible string described by your regex. In your case the regex mathces everything from the first [quote] to the very last [/quote]. To turn this behavior of you have to use the "U" modifier:

```
$body = preg_replace_callback("/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/isU",...);
```

For a list of modifiers see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: That doesn't work, as then it matches the first [quote] to the very last [/quote] in the entire text.

Comment: You are misreading what that `U` modifier does. PHP regexs aren't "greedy" by default; `.*` is greedy by default, the `?` makes it lazy. The `U` inverts the `*` and the `*?` pairing.